# Program hangs when trying to read from child's process stdout

Tags: java, process, io

I wait to start a process, pass an integer to it, and get a value which it prints out. I tried the following (in Windows):

```
public class Example {

    public static Boolean call() throws IOException {
        String mFilename = "f.exe";
        int mParam = 0;
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(mFilename);
        BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader
                (new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
        BufferedWriter output = new BufferedWriter
                (new OutputStreamWriter(p.getOutputStream()));
        output.write(mParam);
        output.flush();
        char retVal = (char) input.read();
        return !(retVal == '0');
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        System.out.println(call());
    }
}
```

`mFilename` is a path to the executable. The process returns 1 for positive input, 0 for negative, and remains in an infinite loop if `mParam` is 0. However, I found out that no matter what value I pass to it, `retVal` is always 1. What am I doing wrong?

Excuse me for deleting the question a few minutes before, I thought the problem was in `retVal` but apparently it was not the only problem in this code.

Child process, written in C++:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>

bool f(int x)
{
    if (x)
        return x > 0;

    while (1)
        Sleep(100);
}

int main()
{
    int x;
    std::cin>>x;
    std::cout<<f(x);
}
```

**Update:**

I found at least one of the errors. Since `mParam` is an integer, which consists of an optional sign and a bunch of digits, and `output.write` writes characters, I need to write my integer as a character array:

```
char[] arr = String.valueOf(mParam).toCharArray();
output.write(arr);
```

However, regardless of the input, after this fix program hangs at

```
char retVal = (char) input.read();
```

Comment: It's hard to know what's going wrong without having the source code of you child process.  Have you tried printing out `retVal` to see that it's actually '1' and not just `!= '0'`?

Comment: @BenLawry, yes, it's actually '1', at least NetBeans debugger shows '1'.

Comment: @prazuber I'm going to drop this into my IDE and give it a try, please disregard my answer, not sure if I am able to delete my own answer.

Comment: Okay, I'm stumped as well.  I copied your child process C++ code into VS.NET 2010, and built a console app ... works as you described when I run it from command-line.  Copied you `Example.java`, got the same results you did.  I tried a few different things, when I experimented, I either always get 1 or the program never returns (hangs).  If you figure it out, please do post an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the solution turned out to be quite simple: `std::cin` just wanted a newline to successfully read the integer. Resulting code is as follows:

```
public Boolean call() throws IOException, InterruptedException, ExecutionException, TimeoutException {
    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(mFilename);
    final BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader
            (new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
    final BufferedWriter output = new BufferedWriter
            (new OutputStreamWriter(p.getOutputStream()));
    output.write(Integer.toString(mParam));
    output.newLine();
    output.flush();

    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
    Callable<Character> readTask = new Callable<Character>() {
        @Override
        public Character call() throws Exception {
            return Character.valueOf((char)input.read());
        }
    };
    Future<Character> future = executor.submit(readTask);
    char readVal;
    try {
        readVal = future.get(3L, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    } finally {
        p.destroy();
        executor.shutdownNow();
    }

    return !(readVal == '0');
}
```

Note that I added support for the 'infinite loop'-case scenario. If we are unable to get the output from stdout in 3 seconds, we throw exception and terminate the child process. I don't process the exception here because the function has to return some result, but in the case of infinite loop I don't have any result to return.